# MySQL cross tab query between Datetime

Tags: mysql, crosstab

I have fields named **hourDate**(Datetime), **appUsed**(readings), **energyUsage**(readings) in my table named **hourlyMetrics_CubicalPrime** and I'm using **cross tab query** as shown below:

```
SELECT hourDate,
sum(IF (Time(hourDate) between '22:59:00' and '23:01:59', appUsed, 0)) as AppUsed_11PM,
sum(IF (Time(hourDate) between '23:59:00' and '23:59:59', appUsed, 0)) as AppUsed_12AM,
sum(IF (Time(hourDate) between '22:59:00' and '23:01:59', energyUsage, 0)) as EnergyUsed_11PM,
sum(IF (Time(hourDate) between '23:59:00' and '23:59:59', energyUsage, 0)) as EnergyUsed_12AM

FROM cubical_database.hourlyMetrics_CubicalPrime 
where Date(hourDate) between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-10'
group by Date(hourDate)
```

Above query give below data:

```
hourDate   AppUsed_11PM  AppUsed_12PM  EnergyUsed_11PM  EnergyUsed_11PM
2016-01-01 01:00:00 5   23  108.283057  2631.7824980000005
2016-01-02 01:00:00 1   14  95.149445   2616.103333
2016-01-03 01:00:00 3   24  168.27166600000004  7898.585555000001
2016-01-04 01:00:00 0   16  700.304167  4599.651944
2016-01-05 01:00:00 0   7   245.32194499999997  2301.689999
2016-01-06 01:00:00 3   14  418.844444  2546.4463889999997
2016-01-07 01:00:00 1   21  739.558055  2838.094999
2016-01-08 01:00:00 35  0   78.631667   69.030277
2016-01-09 01:00:00 1   0   57.676111   56.836389
2016-01-10 01:00:00 0   0   75.67583400000001   74.208054
```

I want sum of readings of appUsed, energyUsage at the time period specified in the queries but not getting exact reading values.

Anybody please suggest me right query.

This is the main query which is showing the actual data in the table:

```
SELECT hourDate, appUsed, energyUsage FROM cubical_database.hourlyMetrics_CubicalPrime where ((Date(hourDate) between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-10') and (TIME(hourDate) between '22:00:00' and '23:59:59')) group by hourDate order by hourDate ASC
```

and it gives output

```
hourDate      appUsed energyUsed
2016-01-01 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-01 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-01 23:59:00 0   0
2016-01-02 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-02 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-02 23:59:00 0   1.928056
2016-01-03 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-03 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-03 23:59:00 0   5050.89
2016-01-04 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-04 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-04 23:59:00 0   0
2016-01-05 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-05 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-05 23:59:00 0   0
2016-01-06 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-06 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-06 23:59:00 0   0
2016-01-07 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-07 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-07 23:59:00 0   0
2016-01-08 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-08 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-08 23:59:00 0   0
2016-01-09 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-09 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-09 23:59:00 0   0
2016-01-10 22:00:00 0   0
2016-01-10 23:00:00 0   0
2016-01-10 23:59:00 0   0
```

This data shows that the cross tab query is giving wrong results.

Comment: what did you get wrong ?

Comment: Please give some sample data to exactly know your problem?

Comment: I'm getting values in the resultant table which I think is the sum of whole day's readings not between the mentioned time period

Comment: @AjayMakwana I updated the question..